# This day in history IV

Tags: riddle, history

I haven't done one of these for almost a year and I'm planning to continue this. The correct answer to This day in history III was found by Mordechai (who just beat Tahel to it).

On this date (03/05/2020), a certain amount of years ago, some sort of event happened. What was it and how many years ago did it occur?

Throughout the air, these winged things fly.
And their destination on a 2D map? High.
Two men, there were
One called Fletcher
Who went to visit Santa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event was

> [The first aircraft to land on the North Pole](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/www.history.com/.amp/this-day-in-history/fletcher-lands-on-the-north-pole)

By

> Joseph Fletcher and William Benedict, on May 3rd 1952, 68 years ago

Explanation of riddle:

> - The winged things are aeroplanes
>  - The destination is the North Pole, which is high (towards the top) on 2D maps
>  - There were two men, William Benedict and Joseph *Fletcher*
>  - They landed an aeroplane for the first time at the North Pole, which is where Santa supposedly is.

Comment: Well done! However, the fly very high clue was rot13(Orpnhfr gur Abegu Cbyr nccrnef irel uvtu hc ba 2Q zncf)

Comment: @WilliamPennanti ahhhh that makes more sense :P I was thinking height wouldn’t work very well on 2d maps lol